# SHA256withECDSA Signature not Verifying, Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, digital-signature, ecdsa

**Update:** The critical aspect is that `kp` (keypair) is generated "outside" this code. This code is an onclick function whereas `kp` is defined in the code that sets up the onclick. Shouldn't matter but that's what seems to be the problem and that's inexplicable.

What's wrong with the following code? It always prints (logs) false for the verification `b` even though the data is the same string `"foo"` and the signature is the same one that was generateded earlier in the code `sig`

```
val sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withECDSA").run {
    initSign(kp.private)
    update("foo".toByteArray())
    sign()
}
Log.d(tag, "sig: " + sig.toString())
val o = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withECDSA")
o.initVerify(kp.public)
o.update("foo".toByteArray())
val b = o.verify(sig)
Log.d(tag, b.toString())
```

Comment: Does `sig` really contain the result of `sign()`? (I'm not familiar with Kotlin.) It should be a byte array

Comment: @pedrofb that's correct (kotlin's real nice, btw). I need to update this question. It works fine when `kp` is initialized just above this code. The problem is when the above code is a closure (say onclick function) whereas `kp` is defined above & outside the closure.  (should be the same behavior in java). THank you.

Comment: You're not generating two key pairs are you?